# How to make a moving animation using winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, animation, pixel

I need to make an animation of a moving ball, using the WinAPI.
I'm doing this using the `Ellipse` function:

```
RECT getBallRect() {
    return {
        // x and y -- coords of ball center
        x - ballRaduis,
        y - ballRaduis,
        x + ballRaduis,
        y + ballRaduis
    };
}
RECT ballrc = getBallRect();
Ellipse(hdc, ballrc.left, ballrc.top, ballrc.right, ballrc.bottom);
```

If a make on next step of timer this

```
x += 1;
y += 1;
```

and will render the ball using code above. Then, ball will be moved right and downward by 1px (Here angle is 45 degrees). But if I want move ball on 5, 10, 30 and others degrees. What should I do?
Of course I can do this

```
x += 1;
y += 2;
```

Now angle will be about 60 degrees, but ball will be moved on 2 pixels on y coord. It's bad for me, because I should move ball only on 1 px every timer tick.

Comment: The `Ellipse` API takes integer arguments. You cannot represent sub-pixel precision using integer device coordinates. If you need sub-pixel rendering, you cannot use GDI.

Comment: Use a floating point value to store the position and round it to the nearest integer every time you render.

Comment: @Snps yes, but It will be not precisely.
I use follow formule
`x += 
 (INT)round(cos(angle))
;`
But -1.0 < cos(angle) < 1.0 and rounded value will be only -1, 0 and 1

Comment: I found solution, but it's not a good way.
`x += speed * (
  (INT)(round(cos(angle) * 5)) % 6
 );
 y += speed * (
  (INT) (round(sin(angle) * 5)) % 6
 );`

Comment: Why are you ignoring Snps' suggestion to *"use a floating point value to store the position and round it to the nearest integer **every time your render**"*?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some simple trigonometry. Currently, what you are doing is you are saying x += cos(45) and y += sin(45), and then you are multiplying each by sqrt(2). So to move the ball at 5 degrees above the horizontal, for example, you want x += cos(5) and y+=sin(5). You can multiply each by sqrt(2) as well, but that doesn't really matter, as it is just a scale factor. Good luck!